# setting bits of a uchar

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to set a `uchar` as follows:

```
uchar num = 0;
    //0
    num <<= 1;
    //1
    num |=1;
    num <<=1;
    //0
    num <<=1;
    //1
    num |=1;
    num <<=1;
    //0
    num <<=1;
    //1
    num |=1;
    num <<=1;
    //0
    num <<= 1;
    //0
    num <<=1;
    //should be 01010100 = 84
    std::cout << " num is " << num << " int " << (unsigned int) num << std::endl;
```

Which should end up with the binary 8-bit sequence 01010100 which is 84 in decimal. However, when I print the output I get is  `num is ® int 168`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `std::bitset` would be a lot clearer.

Comment: @chris this is just a minimal working example, but thanks. I did not know about that function. Which I will use from now on. But either way, this should work AFAIK

Comment: Do the math yourself. 1 << 1 is 2, << 1 is 4, | 1 is 5, << 1 is 10, << 1 is 20, | 1 is 21, << 1 is 42, << 1 is 84, << 1 is 168.

Comment: You're doing one too many shifts.

Answer (score 1):

The last shift is too much.  It multiplies 84 by 2 which gives 168

Answer (score 1):

You're shifting for a zero once too often at the end of your series:

```
//1
num |=1;
num <<=1;
//0
num <<= 1;
//0
num <<=1;
```

This won't generate a binary `100` but rather `1000` thus your end-value will be

```
1010 1000 (168)
```

instead of

```
1010 100 (84)
```

Remove one of those last 0 shifts and you'll be good to go: <kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/6MOztE)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

When you want to "append" a `1`, you should **first shift, then OR the `1`**. Otherwise you shift the just-appended `1` which becomes a `2`, hence your result is exactly twice the number you expected.

```
//1
num <<= 1;
num |= 1;

//0
num <<= 1;
```

Then, your last shift **is correct** (in contrast to the other answers, which are also correct but if you simply remove the last shift your code comments are wrong).